# Django decouple quotation mark

Tags: django

I'm trying to set key=values on .env to configure my app using django-decouple. Does anyone know how to work around values using quotation marks ( ' ) on django decouple? I've tried to set some password using these character but it's ignored

Comment: What's happening when there are quotes? Also, you should use python-decouple instead.

Comment: I'm already using django-decouple, and all others values are working fine. When using quotes, decouple just ignore this characer

Comment: Django-decouple as in https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-decouple, is a deprecated project that's why I mentioned python-decouple as in https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple. Regarding the quotes, .env are texts files so if you open a quote you need to close it and that's why it's probably ignored. Can you provide an example of what you're doing?

Comment: I don’t know what you meant by “ignore” when you say about the quotes. I’ve tried on my project here and it works. Can you post an example of what you’re trying to do?! Maybe it becomes easier to help you out.

Comment: @HigorRossato sorry, i was edting my anwser and type enter mystakly

Comment: @HigorRossato Tks for that. What i'm doing is on .env: mySMTPEmail=mypassword' The quote character at the end of password value is ignored. I've tryied double it for closing, but anyway, when i debugg the password value doesn't get the quote, like: mySMTPEmail=mypassword So, can't authenticate on SMTP server

Comment: You don’t need to close. If the quotes are not part of your password you shouldn’t put them there

Comment: @HigorRossato but that is the problem! They are part... :/

Comment: Hmm so unfortunately I don’t know how to help you. I’ve never had this issue, sorry.